# Script bash always running

Tags: bash, sleep, nohup

I want to create a simple bash script that prints a text every 5 minutes.
Script will be launched at the boot.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do
echo "You received a new mail"
sleep 300
done
```

I tried to use nohup like this

```
nohup script.sh
```

But the output is redirected to nohup.out, I don't want it and the process is not executed in background, it's working until I leave with ctrl+C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily redirect `stdout/stderr` however you want by running:

```
nohup script.sh > someotherfile.
```

The point of `nohup` that it will continue to run when the shell closes, but it doesn't immediately get sent to the background. If you want it to:

```
nohup script.sh > someotherfile &
```

If you forget the `&` the usual `ctrl-z` followed by `bg` works.
In any case if you close the shell/terminal it will continue running. Here's a quick tutorial: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/.

If you want to lookup other options check `setsid`, and also `crontab`. That last one is a bit more flexible in terms of when to run and auto-starting. Here's a first good reference:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job#2369

Comment: I think crontab is more adapted to what I want.
How can I planify my task by command lines ? Because crontab has an interraction part

Comment: No interaction except definition, google `crontab` you'll find plenty of tutorials. To kick it off, hit `crontab -e` - this will open the `cron` file where you can add you tasks (this is persistent). There is also an explanation to get you started. Basically you give a time spec, and your command, and the cron will start!